# How do I convert XML tags with attributes and inner text at the same time into a SimpleXMLElement object in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got a problem when I want to convert an XML string into a SimpleXMLElement object.

This is my PHP code:

```
// XML string
$xmlStr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
  <lastname lang="EN">Smith</lastname>
</document>
XML;

// Convert the XML string into an Array
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$xmlArray = json_decode($json, true);

// Print SimpleXMLElement object
print_r($xml);
echo '<br /><br />';

// Print JSON
print_r($json);
echo '<br /><br />';

// Print XML Array
print_r($xmlArray);
echo '<br /><br />';
```

And I get this result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [lastname] => Smith ) 

{"lastname":"Smith"}

Array ( [lastname] => Smith )
```

But there is no "lang" attribute and I don't know what I'm doing wrong... :(

Anyone can help me, please? Any idea would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you cannot convert SimpleXMLElement to JSON with `json_encode()`. It will not only ignore attributes but also override tags with the same name (taken that they have same depth also). It is not trivial task, so you'd better loop over your `$xml` and form whatever array you what.

Comment: Thanks @sevavietl! I didn't know how `json_encode()` works with SimpleXMLElement objects. But it's in the first conversion from XML string to SimpleXMLElement using `simplexml_load_string($xmlStr)` when it already ignores the 'lang' attribute. The XML is supposed to be well formed so I don't know why the SimpleXMLElement object doesn't include it.

Comment: It contains it but doesn't show with `print_r()` the whole content, as it has quite complex structure. If you will do `var_dump($xml->lastname)` or `print_r($xml->lastname)` you will see that it is itself `SimpleXMLElement` object, and the attributes will be displayed now. [Try it yourself here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/063f6b772609b7e365d871a371df38111150c33d)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much @sevavietl! Now I need to create a class with the same structure using stdClass: `$xml = new stdClass(); $xml->lastname = new stdClass(); $xml->lastname->{'lang'} = 'EN'`. When I do `print_r($xml->lastname->{'lang'})` it shows 'EN', it's ok. Then, I tried `$xml->lastname = 'Smith'` to set the value of the inner text and when I do `print_r($xml->lastname)` the result is 'Smith', perfect, but then I do `print_r($xml->lastname->{'lang'})` again and it shows nothing. How do I set the value of an attribute and the inner text of its tag at the same time using a stdClass?

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to send a SOAP request to a WCF service and I need that kind of class to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: A `stdClass` has no knowledge of "innertext" and "attributes". It has nothing to do with XML. So your actual problem is "what is the structure of object I need to create to send a request to this SOAP service using `SOAPCilent`?". Ignore that you're getting it from XML, talk about the type of data you want to send, and the format the SOAP service expects.

Comment: The web method receives one parameter, a custom class with two fields. The first field is another custom class with some string fields, and the second field is a .NET XmlElement.
To set the text value 'Smith' of the 'lastname' tag I do `$xml->lastname->{'_'}`.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the text value 'Smith' of the 'lastname' tag I do:

```
$xml->lastname->{'_'}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `json_encode` function will not add xml attributes on any the node that is only text. If a final element is just text and you need to use another attribute as lang in this case, you'll have to add another enclosing mark. I always use **_value**, the same as do `Mootools` [XmlToJsObject](https://mootools.net/forge/p/object_fromxml) library.

I wrote a small PHP [test](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t1ga-cpqx) .